# How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException when using Apache Archiva 2.2.1?

Tags: java, maven

When I unpack Apache Archiva 2.2.1 standalone version and start it with `sudo -u archiva env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /bin/bash /var/lib/archiva/apache-archiva-current/bin/archiva console` I get the following exception. The behaviour seems to occur in the `systemd` unit and this seems to cause HTTP error 503 and unhelpful error message `Service Unavailable` in the browser while the `systemd` unit reports working state.

I suspect this happens because Java 9 is used instead of 8 (based on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) and because if I uninstall all `openjdk-9...` packages and restart `archiva.service` it works, so the solution could be to get `archiva` to use OpenJDK 8. It ignores `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` in the `systemd` unit.

```
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/var/lib/archiva/apache-archiva-2.2.1/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/lib/archiva-rest-services-2.2.1.jar!/META-INF/spring-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)
jvm 1    | Caused by: 
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)
jvm 1    | Caused by: 
jvm 1    | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler.init(NamespaceHandler.java:27)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)
jvm 1    | Caused by: 
jvm 1    | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
jvm 1    |      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/URLClassLoader.java:388)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler.init(NamespaceHandler.java:27)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Method.java:535)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Java command used by Archiva in the file `$ARCHIVA_ROOT/conf/wrapper.conf`

Initially this is set to use the Java version from the system path

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.working.dir=..

(More omitted...)
```

Here is an example for using a specific Java installation (on Windows)

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java
wrapper.working.dir=..
```